# How to save temp arrays values to other array, then clear temp and loop again

Tags: javascript, angularjs, arrays

i have method which check if times are having 0.25 between them:

time: '6.00-6.15', value: 6.00
time: '6.15-6.30', value: 6.25  ===  **these are pair**

---

time: '6.00-6.15', value: 6.00
time: '6.30-6.45', value: 6.50  === **these are NOT a pair**

my code can make these pair just fine, but now it adds the value and goes to next, **even** there is a possibility for situation like this:

time: '6.00-6.15', value: 6.00
time: '6.15-6.30', value: 6.25  ===  **these are pair**

time: '6.15-6.30', value: 6.25
time: '6.30-6.45', value 6.50   ===  **these are pair**

Now it only takes first pair, after that i cant use 6.25 value again. 
Heres the code:

```
$scope.countValues = function () {

$scope.temp = [];
$scope.array = [];

var add = 0;

for (var x = add; x < $scope.times.length; x++) {

    if ($scope.temp.length > 0) {
        for (var i = 0; i < $scope.temp.length; i++) {

            if ($scope.times[x].value - 0.25 === $scope.temp[i].value) {

                $scope.temp.push({date: $scope.times[x].date, time: $scope.times[x].time, value: $scope.times[x].value});

            } else {
                $scope.array.push($scope.temp);
                $scope.temp = [];

                add++;
            }
        }
    } else if ($scope.temp.length === 0) {

        $scope.temp.push({date: $scope.times[x].date, time: $scope.times[x].time, value: $scope.times[x].value});
    }
}
};
```

i guess the problem is in the temp array, how i should handle it?
If I do temp.length=0; it removes my values from the real array also.

so:

1. How can I get all possible pairs from the list?
2. How I push values from temp to realDeal array and then clear temp, so array keeps the pushed values?